# Scrollable background in android TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I've got a TextView with a tiled background defined as

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tile" 
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Works ok, but the problem is that when I scroll down to read more text, the background stays in the same place, whereas I'd like it to scroll with the text. 
Any ideas appreciated.

The text view is defined as:

```
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
class="com.example.android.notepad.NoteEditor$LinedEditText"
android:id="@+id/note"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/app_bg_r"
android:textColor="#666666"
android:padding="5dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
android:gravity="top"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:lineSpacingExtra ="7sp"
android:capitalize="sentences" />
```

The class LinedEditText does nothing apart from setting a custom font.

The text view is set in the Activity's onCreate with

```
setContentView(R.layout.note_editor);
```

Comment: Can you also post your TextView xml?  (or code if you are creating it that way)

Comment: Sure, I've put it in the question. Thx

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to get this to work only using the TextView, but if no one else proposes a solution I would recommend wrapping your TextView in a ViewGroup (FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc) of some sort and then wrapping that with a ScrollView. It is probably not the best solution since it adds a lot of views, but it will probably work.

Set the background to the ViewGroup and have it wrap_content around the TextView.  Let the ScrollView handle the scrolling.

You could try it without the extra ViewGroup to see if the background will work on the ScrollView, but you may run into the same issue again.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/app_bg_r" >
      <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"           
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm trying with ScrollView only but it seems something is blocking the scroll... it scrolls a bit (half a line?) and jumps back (oversrcolling?). I think the scrolling of the TextView might be interferring... how to disable it? I can't find any specific attribute

Comment: @Mad Riffer, set the TextView height to wrap_content, erase the scrollbars & fadingEdge declarations from it as well.  Then set the ViewGroup that is around it to have a height of wrap_content.  I'll post an example xml in an edit above.

Comment: Sorry for posting just now. Thanks for the hint, however I did try all of that and more, somehow the solution is still evading me. I'll get back into this when I come back from holidays next week.